# How to sort the output of Find to a psql copy command to load data in order?

Tags: postgresql, bash, psql

I wish to load data to a PostgreSQL DB from a bunch of files that are in multiple folders. I have to load them in order (i.e. files in folders 2020 must be loaded before folders 2021 and so on). This is what I have currently:

```
find  ~/data/inserts/ -type f -exec psql -h db1.cluster-xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 dbname -U admin1 -c "\COPY public.db1(col1,col2) FROM '{}' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;" \;
```

This loads the data in the files, but the files aren't sorted. By Googling, I know you can pipe into `sort` like so:

```
find ~/data/inserts/ -type f -print | sort -z | xargs -r0 echo
```

but I am not sure how to apply it to my case. I am not sure how to use `xargs -r0` even after reading the docs.

Comment: Sorted on *what* ? {inode, name, ctime,atime,mtime, directory order} ?

Comment: Sorted on the file name. My files are:

to_load/year=2021/month=2/run-161779504564
to_load/year=2021/month=3/run-161779504564
to_load/year=2021/month=4/run-161779504564

I wish to process them in order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `-print0` instead of `-print` as `find` argument:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Pipe the sorted null delimited output of find to while loop
find ./ -type f -print0 | sort -z |
while IFS= read -r -d '' input_file || [ -n "$input_file" ]; do
  # Now execute the pgsql command to copy from STDIN rather than named file
  psql \
    -h db1.cluster-xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -U admin1 dbname \
    -c "COPY public.db1(col1,col2) FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;" \
    <"$input_file" # This provide the input file as STDIN
done
```